# DexException Multiple dex files define in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, jaxb, dex, android-multidex

In my android project am using two JAXB libraries jaxp-ri (for XMLGregorianCalendarImpl class) and jaxb-api(for object to xml conversion). I have added these two libraries in build.gradle file.

But when I building my project am getting below mentioned errors

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Ljavax/xml/stream/events/Namespace;
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Ljavax/xml/stream/events/Namespace;
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Ljavax/xml/stream/events/Namespace;
```

Build.gradle file

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    compile group: 'com.sun.org.apache', name: 'jaxp-ri', version: '1.4'

    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.1'

}
```

can any one please help on this? how can I solve this problem?

**Edit**

Complete build.gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.cdac.xmlparsing"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile group: 'com.sun.org.apache', name: 'jaxp-ri', version: '1.4'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.1'
}
```

Comment: Is this the only build.gradle file in your project?

Comment: what is your minimum sdk version ?

Comment: @Kelevandos this build.gradle file in app, and the regular one in project directory.

Comment: @AsutoshPanda minimum sdk version is 15, now I have given the complete gradle file content in the question section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By simply declaring **multiDexEnabled true** in module-level build.gradle, works only if  your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher.

If your minSdkVersion is lower than 21, in addition to the above step, you need to have the multidex support library as a dependency

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

You can read the details are here - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: When I add the required dependencies to build.gradle (module app) again it throws same DexException


          compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.1'   and   

    compile group: 'com.sun.org.apache', name: 'jaxp-ri', version: '1.4'

Comment: Thanks, it solves the problem when adding the dependencies using jars not with gradle scripts.

Answer (score 2):

use below build.gradle(Module:app).you can add your required dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.administrator.firstproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    // viewslider dependancies
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/poi-3.7.jar')


}
```

Comment: When I add the required dependencies to build.gradle (module app) again it throws same DexException


          compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.1'   and   

    compile group: 'com.sun.org.apache', name: 'jaxp-ri', version: '1.4'

Comment: Thanks, it solves the problem when adding the dependencies using jars not with gradle scripts.